# How can i create new instance of class using field type on runtime

Tags: java, dynamic

I have this class

```
public static class ExampleClass {
    private ExampleObject exampleObject;

    public ExampleObject getExampleObject() {
        return exampleObject;
    }

    public void setExampleObject(ExampleObject exampleObject) {
        this.exampleObject = exampleObject;
    }
}

public class ExampleObject {
    private String exampleProp;

    public String getExampleProp() {
        return exampleProp;
    }

    public void setExampleProp(String exampleProp) {
        this.exampleProp = exampleProp;
    }
}
```

I created a loop to get field types of ExampleClass. How can I create a new instance using field type on runtime? My field type is:

[image: field type]

I try this 
`Class c = Class.forName(fieldType.getName()); 
var ins = c.newInstance();`

But code throws exception like this

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.Main$ExampleObject.<init>()
  at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3350)
  at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2554)
  at com.example.CreatorFactory.getCreator(CreatorFactory.java:29)
  at com.example.AutoFill.fill(AutoFill.java:15)
  at com.example.AutoCreate.<init>(AutoCreate.java:15)
  at com.example.AutoCreate.build(AutoCreate.java:23)
  at com.example.Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

Comment: Java reflect api: `Class c=Class.forName("ExampleClass");  ExampleClass s =(ExampleClass)c.newInstance();`

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html

Comment: Why, specifically, are you wanting to do this?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I develop an auto-create library like AutoFixture (https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) using java. So I need this. But I can't create a new instance using field types (for nested classes)

Comment: @PatrickChen I wrote this Class c = Class.forName(fieldType.getName()); var ins = c.newInstance(); but code throws exception like this java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.Main$ExampleObject

Comment: @PatrickChen I changed code like this **Class c = Class.forName(fieldType.getName()); var ins = c.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();** but still throws error **java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.Main$ExampleObject.<init>()**

Comment: @ErtuğrulÜngör fieldType.getName().toString() this might help

Comment: @backdoor fieldType.getName() already returns String

Comment: @ErtuğrulÜngör Is `fieldType.getName()` returns the class name? and Do you have a default constructor method inside the class?

Comment: @PatrickChen I don't have a default constructor. I am writing a library. Maybe developer who using this library can't write a constructor. It's a dynamic

Comment: @ErtuğrulÜngör, can you create a new object by `new ExampleClass()`, If not, how can you expect the JVM to do it for you. JVM will create a default constructor if you don't have any constructors in this class. But if you do have any constructors which is not a default constructor, you need to define a default constructor because JVM will not create a default one for you anymore

Comment: @PatrickChen fieldType.getName() returns `com.example.Main$ExampleObject`

Comment: @ErtuğrulÜngör, maybe post all your code and make it easier for us to discuss it.